# Return statements when inverting a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I'm am doing some problems on leetcode and came across the following problem:

```
Invert a binary tree:

     4
   /   \
  2     7
 / \   / \
1   3 6   9

to
     4
   /   \
  7     2
 / \   / \
9   6 3   1
```

I have the solution but wouldn't my code work with just the first return statement? Wouldn't the first statement serve as the base case and be enough? Why does the last return statement have to be there?

```
public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    TreeNode temp = root.left;
    root.left = root.right;
    root.right = temp;

    invertTree(root.left);
    invertTree(root.right);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"why?"*? If you remove the second `return root;` the code won't compile

Comment: Better question: Why does the method return anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation modifies the `TreeNode` that you received.
It's generally not safe to assume that this is allowed.
You should double-check in the requirements,
if it's not mentioned explicitly, it's better to not make this assumption.

The [method's signature](https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/) requires to return a `TreeNode`.
The intention is probably to *not* modify the input tree,
and return a new, inverted tree.

```
public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    TreeNode newRoot = new TreeNode(root.val);
    newRoot.left = invertTree(root.right);
    newRoot.right = invertTree(root.left);
    return newRoot;
}
```

If it was allowed to modify the input tree,
then the method signature would be better as `void`,
and then your implementation would be fine as it is, with the last `return` dropped.

Comment: You're assuming that the code should create a *new* reversed tree, rather than an in-place reversal, which is what question code is doing. Nothing in the question says it has to be a new tree.

Comment: @Andreas Since the return type is `TreeNode` and not `void`, it seems a reasonable assumption that a new tree is expected, and the original should be left unmodified.

Comment: That depends on whether the method signature was given to OP to complete and OP misunderstood the assignment, or it is just OP returning a value when not needed. As I said, you are *assuming*, since we don't know the details of the assignment. But you've now stated/clarified your assumption about the intent, so down-vote removed.

Comment: @Andreas it's from an online judge: the signature was given. https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/

Comment: @janos Thanks. Good to know. Would have been nice if that had been stated in the question. If you based your answer on that information not in evidence, it would have been nice if your answer then had referenced it. Adding up-vote for being only answer to address the issue of creating new tree.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually use the returned TreeNode inside the recursion.

If you:

1. Remove the last return statement AND
2. Remove the first return statement AND
3. Change the method signature to be `void` (from `TreeNode`)

You should achieve the same thing (but without returning a copy of the input).

Comment: Thanks! But does the last return actually do any work or is it there just because it has to return something?

Comment: As is, it does work. It returns the tree to the caller (on the first call). The base case is just there to end the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

All possible exit points of your method must have a return statement. In the definition `public TreeNode invertTree(...)` you promised to return a `TreeNode` at all times. If you would omit the last return statement, your promise would be broken in case of `root != null` -- therefore the compiler wouldn't accept such code.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, it is not clear what is the purpose of returning a value at all. It certainly it is not needed for the algorithm, and you do not need it to retrieve the root treenode (since you should have it for the initial invocation).

So you could change it to:

```
public void invertTree(TreeNode root) {
  if(root == null) {
    return;
  }
  TreeNode temp = root.left;
  root.left = root.right;
  root.right = temp;

  invertTree(root.left);
  invertTree(root.right);
}
```

or even, if you are particularly opposed to `return`s:

```
public void invertTree(TreeNode root) {
  if(root != null) {
    TreeNode temp = root.left;
    root.left = root.right;
    root.right = temp;

    invertTree(root.left);
    invertTree(root.right);
  }
}
```

But as long as the method declares that it returns a value (i.e. it is not a `void` method), it should have a final `return` (or `throw`) statement in all of its branches.

Comment: Although that's how I would do, the code does'nt compile, you can try yourself at https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/#/description

Comment: Since you are talking about an exercise that already gives you the definition of the method, you should not change that method definition (`TreeNode` for `void`) and expect the **automated tool** to accept it. The code above compiles and works if you try it on your PC as part of a standalone program; but a tool that expects the original method definition may have an issue with that change. And if you do not change the original method definition, then you must return a value.

Comment: Thanks, I was not specific enough!

Answer (score -1):

While your method signature returning an object of type TreeNode, the compiler expect from the method to return something that can be considered as TreeNode.
I think this is the reason of the last return, because you can return null and your method will have the same behavior.

```
public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    TreeNode temp = root.left;
    root.left = root.right;
    root.right = temp;

    invertTree(root.left);
    invertTree(root.right);

    return null;
}
```